# Change audio file on button click

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to change the audio file on a button click and am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: audio.load is not a function

My code is below, the idea is to press the button and then the audio file will change.

Without the `audio.load()` line, the code will run and the `src` will update, but the audio does not change. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <br>
  <audio controls>
    <source src = "audio_file_1.mp3"
      id="audio" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element!
  </audio>
  <br>
  <button onClick="changeAudio();">Change</button>
</body>
<script src="temp.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// temp js
var a = 1;
function changeAudio() {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (a==1) {
    audio.src = 'audio_file_1.mp3';
    a = 2;
  }
  else {
    audio.src = 'audio_file_2.mp3';
    a = 1;
  }
  audio.load();
}

changeAudio();
```

(also, if anyone knows example sound files that I can use instead of the `audio_file_1.mp3` and `audio_file_2.mp3`, I would be happy to update the code so anyone can run it more easily)

---

Edit WRT Rob M's answer:

For anyone with the same problem, the solution is to change two lines:

First, in the HTML code, the `<audio control>` should turn to `<audio control id="audio_id">`

Second, in the javascript code the `audio.load()` should turn to `document.getElementById('audio_id').load();`

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `.load()` on the actual `<audio>` element, not the `<source>` element?

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right, my mistake, if you want write an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `.load()` event on a `<source>` tag, it is on the `<audio>` tag - update your code to call `load()` on the parent `<audio>` tag and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are trying to access to `<audio>` element by its `id` attribute, but you haven't set id attribute to audio tag.
It must be something like this

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src = "audio_file_1.mp3"
      id="track" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element!
</audio>
```

And changing audio file:

```
var a = 1;
function changeAudio() {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (a==1) {
    document.getElementById('track') = 'audio_file_1.mp3';
    a = 2;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('track') = 'audio_file_2.mp3';
    a = 1;
  }
  audio.load();
}

changeAudio();
```

Comment: the source does have an id in my code, set as `id="audio"` and, as Rob's answer points out, you must use the `.load()` function on the `<audio>` element, but can change the source using the `<source>` element. (although, your code will still work and is more concise than mine)